# Using mysqli_stmt_bind_param in SET operation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Whenever I try to use mysqli_stmt_bind_param to use a variable as a column name in a SET operation, it seemingly fails. Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding something?

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', '******', 'db');
$query = "UPDATE stock SET ? = '4' WHERE storeID = 1";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $shirtSize);
$shirtSize = "whiteSmall";

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: You __cannot__ bind column and table names.

Comment: It is written in a manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-parameters But why read it, huh?

Comment: If you think about it it will make sense. A `prepare` send the SQL to the server where it is compiled and optimised. It is not possible to compile or optimise a query if you do not know what columns/tables are going to be used in that query

Comment: @u_mulder I’m still learning, there’s no need to be rude and discouraging. Just because I don’t understand something doesn’t mean I haven’t researched it myself.

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, it makes sense now. Is what I’m trying to do possible, or at least a decent practice?